# How to disable certain rules in prettier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

I upgraded prettier v to 2.14 from 1.x and would like to disable certain rules in prettier v2 like for ex I would want the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadMoreHandler();
}, [loadMoreHandler]);
```

to be like:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
      loadMoreHandler();
  },
  [loadMoreHandler]
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you better just dig into it, it's not all that hard.
Here is the link webpage you are looking for.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: I dont know what is the rule for the above example. Otherwise I know where I can add the rules.